# Link Objective-C application to C++ static library

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, static-libraries, clang

I am trying to use Xcode to build an Objective-C desktop application that links against a static C++ library. I am using the Apple's clang compiler. I am getting the following linker error:

```
Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Developer/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -syslibroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -o /Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sl-marketplace-analysis-exomzzahbygseghhwoeclcvpooeo/Build/Products/Debug/sl marketplace analyitics.app/Contents/MacOS/sl marketplace analyitics -lcrt1.10.6.o -L/Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sl-marketplace-analysis-exomzzahbygseghhwoeclcvpooeo/Build/Products/Debug -L/Users/andrew/Projects/sl-marketplace-analysis/platform/mac/sl marketplace analyitics/../../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sl-marketplace-analysis-exomzzahbygseghhwoeclcvpooeo/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sl-marketplace-analysis-exomzzahbygseghhwoeclcvpooeo/Build/Intermediates/sl marketplace analyitics.build/Debug/sl marketplace analyitics.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sl marketplace analyitics.LinkFileList -framework Cocoa -lcore -lSystem /Developer/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a -F/Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sl-marketplace-analysis-exomzzahbygseghhwoeclcvpooeo/Build/Products/Debug
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libcore.a(test.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in libcore.a(test.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems like it isn't linking against the C++ std library. Is this the problem and if so, how to I ensure that it links against it?

**Update**:

If I add a blank cpp file to the build then everything compiles and runs fine. I just seem to need a way to tell the linker to link against the C++ std library. I have tried looking through all of the build settings in Xcode but can't seem to find anything that helps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try adding -lstdc++ or -lc++ (depending on which C++ runtime your static library expects)
to "Other Linker Flags" under "Build Setting":

[image]

Comment: I encountered the same problem and was looking for this solution for the whole day. Thanks for sharing it, works like a charm

Comment: Thank you!!! I had a static library that was a combination of Objective-C, C++, and Objective-C++. The library itself doesn't include this flag when building but required for some reason when using the library in my iOS application. I have no idea why.

Comment: @jocull: When you build a static library the resulting files are not linked, so libraries are not required until the archive is linked as part of the final application.

Comment: Xcode5 appears to have broken this again. The -lstdc++ no longer works - Xcode5 just refuses to allow any library that's using any C++. Apple's brilliant (non-existent) testing strikes again! ;)

Comment: Note, if you are not sure, then in your Static Library search  "CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" in build settings.
If its libc++ then use -lc++ if its libstdc++ then use: -lstdc++

Answer (score 3):

Having same issue with Xcode 6, i have solved it by linking  "**libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib**"  in the "**Link Binary with Libraries**" build phase & adding **-lstdc++** to "**Other Linker Flags**" under Build Setting

Comment: Thanks Urmi, this has solved my problems, although I did NOT need to add the -lstdc++ to "Other Linker Flags". In my case, the application target itself is pure Obj-C and does NOT need c++, neither language nor standard libraries. However, I need to link against external 3rd-party static libraries that make heavy use of C++ (e.g. an audio/video engine we bought). As they are static libs, we must "help them" by adding the C++ standard libs to our app. for some reason Xcode does NOT do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird that `libcore.a` is looking for a class named `Init` in the `std::ios_base` namespace.  I don't think `std::ios_base::Init` is a standard class.

Aside from that, you might want to check that `libcore.a` actually includes `x86_64` code.  You can use the `file` command to check.  For example:

```
$ file /usr/lib/libz.dylib
/usr/lib/libz.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/lib/libz.dylib (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/usr/lib/libz.dylib (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

If the `file` command output doesn't include a “`for architecture x86_64`” line, you can't use the library to create a 64-bit executable.

Comment: I have control of that library too (i am building it within the same Xcode workspace. It is built with x86_64.

Answer (score -1):

**Other Linker Flags -lstdc++** Didn't help for me in Xcode5.
But find out similar thing in **Apple LLVM 5.0 - Lnaguage - C++**

default setting was **libc++(LLVM C++ standard~blabla)** and changed it to **libstdc++(GNU thing)**

Now there is no error with linking!!! and now I have to find out it runs fine.

anyway thanks for advice.

Comment: Same problem - -lstdc++ seems to have no effect in Xcode5. The suggested fix in this answer has no effect (and shouldn't)

Comment: Yeah, if you use libc++, you should link against libc++.  If you use libstdc++ (which is old and deprecated, so don't), you should link against libstdc++.