# Apple O-Linker Error when try to use OpenCV framework in already working project

Tags: ios, opencv, undefined-symbol, xcode4.6

What I have done is used some code from the [tutorial](https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial) based on the openCV framework.
From the `EdgeDetectionSample.cpp` file, I import the code.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
>         cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, int) in opencv2(system.o)
>         cv::Exception::Exception(cv::Exception const&) in opencv2(system.o)
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
>         cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         __ZN2cvL7setSizeERNS_3MatEiPKiPKmb in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const&, cv::Range const&) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const*) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::diag(int) const in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::reserve(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         ...
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::__init(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         __ZN2cvL7setSizeERNS_3MatEiPKiPKmb in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const&, cv::Range const&) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const*) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::diag(int) const in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         cv::Mat::reserve(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         ...
>     "std::_*1::*_vector_base_common::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
>         std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         std::_*1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::*_append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
>         ...
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
>         cv::Exception::formatMessage() in opencv2(system.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please Help me Out with this. I am not able to get read of those errors.

Comment: That looks like the C++ runtime library needs linking in.  Some of your code must be implemented in C++.

Comment: yes some code is in c++. Please, tell me how I can linking in the missing C++ runtime library(s)?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950388/link-objective-c-application-to-c-static-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project is linked against `libstd++ (GNU C++ standard library)`, but latest OpenCV was linked against `libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++ 11 support)`, so you have two ways to fix this:

1. Link you project against libc++
2. Rebuild OpenCV with libstd++.

To link your project with libc++, go to  -> Build Settings -> find 'C++ standard library' row and select libc++ there.