# Apple Mach-o Linker Error Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I have used an Third party framework in my app called IDchecker and when i run the code i get a linker error. i tried adding -ObjC and  -lstdc++  to the other Linker Flag but it doesnt work for me. Can u tell whats the actual reason for this kind of error ?

```
Apple Mach-o Linker Error
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in IDCheckerSDK(IDCheckerSDK.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in IDCheckerSDK(IDCCameraViewController.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in IDCheckerSDK(IDCImageProcessor.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in IDCheckerSDK(IDCFaceLinkViewController.o)
      __GLOBAL__I_a in IDCheckerSDK(UIImage+OpenCV.o)
```

Comment: Can you try adding the  libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib in build phases of your target.. Not tried but i am suspecting that it has got to do with linking the C++ lib. oh and btw lstdc++ will not work in xcode 5 (if ur using it)

Comment: you are right... it worked. please post the answer so that i can mark your answer as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion and for the use of others...

There seems to be a problem in linking the C++ lib. 
Please include `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib` in the build phases of your target. 
this should solve the issue

Hope this helps...

*************EDIT*******************

Thanks to @trojenfoe for pointing this out.
although this is currently working , for a  more stable solution it would be advisable to link to `libstdc++.dylib`. under `Link binary with libraries`  of `Build Phases` tab of your target.

Comment: Why does this solve the issue and linking against `-lstdc++` (as the OP states he has tried) not solve the issue?  Can you explain please.

Comment: @trojanfoe In xcode 5 -lstdc++ does not work. People are facing this issue . For your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950388/link-objective-c-application-to-c-static-library.

Comment: That's one person's perspective that it doesn't work under Xcode 5; my experience is different, however I don't add it to *Other Linker Flags*, but put it into the *Link binary with libraries* section of the *Build Phases*.  I believe linking against such a specific version of the library is a bad idea and will lead to issues when/if the library is updated.

Comment: I haven't advised him anything different than what you are saying.

Comment: Yes you have; see my imminent answer.

Comment: Okay i'll check it out once you post it

Answer (score 1):

The framework might not have been compiled with i386 arch.

Run a:

```
file yourframework.framework/yourframework
e.g. file Test.framework/Test
```

If you can't see **for architecture i386** in the output, then that specific arch is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted answer is a mistake as linking against such a specific version of the runtime library will lead to issues when/if the library is updated.

Instead, rather than using the *Other Linker Flags* build setting, I would advise you link against `libstdc++.dylib` within the *Link Binary With Libraries* section of the *Build Phases* project settings.  I have done this under Xcode 5 without issue (however I linked against `libc++.dylib`, but I don't believe that difference is important).

Comment: What issues linking to a specified version of the lib would one face?

Comment: @XCodian That's fine, but will it work fine in 6 months time or under a different version of OSX?

Comment: @PrathameshSaraf The issue would be that version 6.0.9 of libstdc++ doesn't exist as it's now 6.0.10.

Comment: Fair enough .. thanks for correcting me.. With your permission can i correct my answer ?

Comment: @XCodian This is a permanent solution and the key is to link against `libstdc++.dylib` and not `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib`.

Comment: @PrathameshSaraf You don't need my permission for anything in this world.

Comment: thanks Trojanfoe and Saraf. the answer libstdc++.dylib is working fine

Comment: i have a small doubt what is the difference it is by adding /usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib   AND adding libstdc++.dylib

Comment: @XCodian You don't need both.  If you are linking via the settings suggested in my answer then I didn't think you even saw where libstdc++ was located, it simply appeared as libstdc++.